# Django: Is it possible to use a capitalization method such as capfirst in templates but instead in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

In templates a usual statement such as `{{field.value|capfirst}}` capitalize the first letter of a string. In an input field this looks like

```
<input type="text" name="{{field.name}}" value="{{field.value|capfirst}}">
```

In my template I do not define explicitly the input fields, instead I have the following:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I do `{{field|capfirst}}` it won't work. As you may guess, all my fields are given in `forms.py`, for example:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'description')
```

How can I define `capfirst` in `forms.py` (or `views.py`  or `templatetags`)? I want to keep a simple for loop in my template as shown above. As you can see I just want to capitalize the first letter of `field.value` to show it on the screen, no need to transfer this info to the database (no update needed), I just want to show it on the screen... is it possible?

Comment: because the field in your template refer to the <input> tag, not the text within the input value.

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize the first letter after form submission, you can use the [clean_](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method in a form to modify the value before rendering it on the form like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'description')

    def clean_name(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['name'].capitalize()
```

the [capitalize()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/capitalize.html) is a python function that capitalizes the first letter of a string

the whole purpose of forms.py is to render the form element for you, you can add attributes, add classes, and modify values within the Django form renderer. If you want to modify the HTML of the form inputs then rather not use the forms.py, write a normal HTML form and receive it with the request.POST.get().

Comment: Couldn't find it in the docs; is `clean_fieldname()` also called when it's empty (and therefore possibly produce an error here)?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work... or I need to call the function somewhere else?

Comment: maybe this works in submission only? I actually don't mind what happens in submission, what I want is once everything is submitted, validated and fine, I want to show it on the screen

Comment: @statsconchris yes this only work after form submission, if you want every user input to show capitalize then that would required javascript